# Create Javascript Object Having Nested Parent Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, adonis.js

I am working on a Nodejs project. I have to create a function which takes an object (a child category) like:

```
{
    id: 65,
    name: 'Outdoor',
    parent_id: 2
}
```

Now I want my function to check for the parent category by using `parent_id` from database and return an array/object like this:

```
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Furniture',
    parent: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Residential',
        parent: {
            id: ...,
            name: ...,
            parent: {
                and so on..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
* _get_category_parents(category, _array) {

    if(_array === undefined) _array = []

    if( category.parent_id !== 0 ) {
      const c_parent = yield this.Database.from('categories').where('id', '=', category.parent_id)
      _array.push({id: c_parent[0].id, name: c_parent[0].name})
      yield this._get_category_parents(c_parent[0], _array)

    }

    return _array

  }
```

And calling this function like this:

```
const parents = yield this._get_category_parents(category)
```

This returns me an array of parents like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Furniture"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Residential"
    }
]
```

I want Residential object to be appended in Furniture's parent node.

I have spent too much time on this but not getting what I want. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The generators implementation seems tricky... I believe with promises or async/await would be easier

Comment: I would think in terms of simple recursion.

Comment: @ali which database are you using? Some databases support recursive queries which allows you to fetch all of the data using a single query – ie, rather than using javascript to query one record at a time.

Comment: @naomik I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to think about is a recursive solution.

Since you're calling a database, it's probably unlikely, but if the lookup by id is synchronous, you might do it with code something like the following (note that I'm faking a db here):

```js
const getHierarchy = (lookup, child) => {
  const {id, name, parent_id} = lookup(child) || 
        {id: null, name: null, parent_id: 0}
  return parent_id == 0  
         ? {id, name, parent_id} 
         :  {...{id, name},  ...{parent: getHierarchy(lookup, {parent_id})}}
}

const items = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Residential', parent_id: 5},
  {id: 2, name: 'Furniture', parent_id: 1},  
  {id: 3, name: 'Other', parent_id: 0},   
  {id: 4, name: 'FooBar', parent_id: 3},   
  {id: 5, name: 'Stuff', parent_id: 0} 
]

const lookup = child => items.find(item => item.id == child.parent_id)

const item = {id: 65, name: 'Outdoor', parent_id: 2}

console.log(getHierarchy(lookup, item))
```

You would have to write an appropriate `lookup` function, presumably using `this.Database.from(...)`.  You might also want to simplified version that bakes in your `lookup` function, in which case, you might write

```
const getAncestry = (item) => getHierarchy(lookup, item)
```

If, as seems more likely, your lookup is asynchronous, then that will affect `getHierarchy` and how you call it.  Here's one possibility:

```js
const getHierarchy = async (lookup, child) => {
  const {id, name, parent_id} = await lookup(child) || 
        {id: null, name: null, parent_id: 0}
  return parent_id == 0  
         ? {id, name, parent_id} 
         :  {...{id, name},  ...{parent: await getHierarchy(lookup, {parent_id})}}
}

const items = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Residential', parent_id: 5},
  {id: 2, name: 'Furniture', parent_id: 1},  
  {id: 3, name: 'Other', parent_id: 0},   
  {id: 4, name: 'FooBar', parent_id: 3},   
  {id: 5, name: 'Stuff', parent_id: 0} 
]

const lookup = async child => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(
    () => resolve(items.find(item => item.id == child.parent_id)), 
    1000
  )
)
const getAncestry = async item => getHierarchy(lookup, item)

const item = {id: 65, name: 'Outdoor', parent_id: 2}

getAncestry(item).then(console.log)
```

Note the change in how you call the function.  You need to call `.then()` on the resulting promise to get any useful behavior.

Comment: Wow.. Worked like a charm. Just what I needed. That was a single shot solution. Thanks a lot Scott Sauyet.